# is nested yaml inventory file for ansible supported?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use a yaml file as inventory file which looks like below:

`- prod:
    webserver:
      hosts:
        example1.com
    db_servers:
      hosts:
        example2.com
        example3.com
- stag:
    webserver:
      hosts:
        example3.com`

It doesn't seem to work, and I couldn't find much info on ansible docs arounf yaml inventory file. Is the above supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not supported. You are supposed to have different inventories for production/testing.

You can only define single dependency tree like this:

```
webserver:
  hosts:
    example1:
db_servers:
  hosts:
    example2:
    example3:
test:
  children:
    webserver:
    db_servers:
```

In this case group `test` is a parent of `webserver` and `db_servers`.