# Ansible Handle Multiple Elements in Hash

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to load a list of hosts in my playbook to provision a KVM. I need to key this off of the hosts.yml because another playbook is going to take the hosts and connect to them once they're up.

This my hosts.yml:

```
kvm:
  hosts:
    kvm01
dcos:
  dcos-bootstrap:
    hosts:
      dcos-bootstrap
    vars:
      lv_size: "10g"

  dcos-masters:
    hosts:
      dcos-master-1
    vars:
      lv_size: "50g"

  dcos-agents:
    hosts:
      dcos-agent-1
      dcos-agent-2
    vars:
      lv_size: "50g"
```

So on a single KVM I run this playbook to create the logical volumes for each of the Virtual Machines corresponding to the dcos hosts:

```
---
- hosts: kvm
  tasks:
  - name: Get a list of vm's to create
    include_vars: 
      file: "../hosts.yml"

  - name: Verify the host list
    debug: var=dcos
    when: dcos is defined

  - name: Provision Volume Groups
    lvol:
      vg: vg01
      lv: "{{ item.value.hosts }}"
      size: "{{ item.value.vars.lv_size }}"
    with_dict: "{{ dcos }}"
```

This works fine until you include more than one host for a group. I've tried other loops but I'm not sure how to continue. How can I iterate over the hash while working on each host in a group?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Ansible so I really wasn't sure how to accomplish what I wanted. I initially tried to parse the hosts file myself, not knowing that Ansible does this for me. Now I know...

All of the host and group data is stored in host_vars and groups. All I needed to do what use this like so:

```
vars: 
  dcoshosts: "{{ groups['dcos'] }}"
tasks:
  - name: List groups
    debug:
      msg: "{{ groups }}" 

  - name: Get All DCOS hosts
    debug:
      msg: "Host: {{ item }}"
    with_items: 
      - "{{ dcoshosts }}"

  - name: Provision Volume Groups
    lvol:
      vg: vg01
      lv: "{{ item }}"
      size: "{{ hostvars[item].lv_size }}"
    with_items: "{{ dcoshosts }}"
```

I ended up using a hosts.ini file instead of yaml because the ini worked and the yaml didn't. Here it is to complete the picture:

```
[dcos-masters]
dcos-master-1
dcos-master-2

[dcos-masters:vars]
lv_size="50g"

[dcos-agents]
dcos-agent-1
dcos-agent-2

[dcos-agents:vars]
lv_size="50g"

[dcos-bootstraps]
dcos-bootstrap

[dcos-bootstraps:vars]
lv_size="10g"

[dcos:children]
dcos-masters
dcos-agents
dcos-bootstraps
```

Thanks to everybody for the help and pushing me to my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You try to reinvent what Ansible provides already.

This is the Ansbile way of life:

Define your hosts and groups in an inventory file `dcos.ini`:

```
[dcos-bootstraps]
dcos-bootstrap

[dcos-masters]
dcos-master-1

[dcos-agents]
dcos-agent-1
dcos-agent-2

[dcos:children]
dcos-bootstraps
dcos-masters
dcos-agents
```

Then you customize the group parameters in group variables.

Bootstrap parameters in `groups_vars/dcos-bootstraps.yml`:

```
---
lv_size: 10g
```

Masters parameters in `group_vars/dcos-masters.yml`:

```
---
lv_size: 50g
```

Agents parameters in `group_vars/dcos-agents.yml`:

```
---
lv_size: 50g
```

And your playbooks becomes quite simple:

```
---
- hosts: dcos
  tasks:
    - name: Provision Volume Groups
      lvol:
        vg: vg01
        lv: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        size: "{{ lv_size }}"
```

When you run this each host gets its `lv_size` parameter based on the group membership of the host.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I'm not trying to create the logical volume on each of the dcos hosts - i'm trying to create logical volumes on a single machine (KVM) corresponding to the dcos hostnames. I've updated my question to make my intent clearer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you I suspect you have incorrect data.
If you want your `hosts` to be a list, you should make it so:

```
kvm:
  hosts:
    kvm01
dcos:
  dcos-bootstrap:
    hosts:
      - dcos-bootstrap
    vars:
      lv_size: "10g"

  dcos-masters:
    hosts:
      - dcos-master-1
    vars:
      lv_size: "50g"

  dcos-agents:
    hosts:
      - dcos-agent-1
      - dcos-agent-2
    vars:
      lv_size: "50g"
```

Note the hyphens.

And to your question: if you are not going to use "group" names in your loop (like `dcos-bootstrap`, etc.), you can use `with_subelements`:

```
  - name: Provision Volume Groups
    lvol:
      vg: vg01
      lv: "{{ item.1 }}"
      size: "{{ item.0.vars.lv_size }}"
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ dcos }}"
      - hosts
```

Comment: You're correct that making the host file into a list resolves the loop issue however it breaks it's use as a hosts file. When I run ansible-playbook -i hosts.yml site.yml I get this on dcos: skipping: no hosts matched. I need this file to be usable as a hosts file.

Comment: Your original file works as inventory file by coincidence. You should definitely refactor your environment.

Comment: It wasn't by coincidence, it's on purpose :) I don't want to/shouldn't have to enter my host information twice. The hosts are already in the hosts file...why not use that file?

Comment: "By coincidence" I mean, you have incorrect YAML format. See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/hosts.yaml and https://stackoverflow.com/a/43140179/2795592.